# Width of tablenotes and caption (threeparttable)

Tags: captions, width, threeparttable, tablenotes

Could you help me adjusting the width of the `\tablenotes` and `\caption`in this MWE? I want both to be whole page and not just as wide as the table.

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore}}
      \label{tab:KorrelationenBilder}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}llrrr@{}}        
     % \toprule
&    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Pupillenweite} \\
& & Gesamt & Neutral & Negativ\\ \midrule
Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1 & & &&  \\
\midrule 
       &  Gesamt      & .000   & -.112 & .096 \\ 
         \midrule
        & Neutral        & -.146       &  -.192 & -.070  \\  
         \midrule
        & Negativ      &  .086    & -.042 & .172  \\  
                   \midrule

Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2 & & && \\
\midrule  
       &  Gesamt     & -.135    & -.223 & -.036    \\ 
         \midrule
        & Neutral        &-.286 &  -.293 & -.219  \\  
         \midrule
        & Negativ      &  -.013    & -.136 & .087   \\  
                   \midrule

                   Wiedererkennen Tag 2 & & &&  \\
\midrule  
       &  Gesamt     & -.201  & -.295 & -.079    \\ 
         \midrule
        & Neutral         & -.179       &  -.252 & -.082  \\  
         \midrule
        & Negativ     &  -.182     & -.280 & -.059  \\  
                   \midrule
       \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
         {\small
            \textit{Anmerkungen.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
         }
      \end{tablenotes}
   \end{threeparttable}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
      \caption{{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore}}
      \label{tab:KorrelationenBilder}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}llrrr@{}}
     % \toprule
&    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Pupillenweite} \\
& & Gesamt & Neutral & Negativ\\ \midrule
Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1 & & &&  \\
\midrule
       &  Gesamt      & .000   & -.112 & .096 \\
         \midrule
        & Neutral        & -.146       &  -.192 & -.070  \\
         \midrule
        & Negativ      &  .086    & -.042 & .172  \\
                   \midrule

Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2 & & && \\
\midrule
       &  Gesamt     & -.135    & -.223 & -.036    \\
         \midrule
        & Neutral        &-.286 &  -.293 & -.219  \\
         \midrule
        & Negativ      &  -.013    & -.136 & .087   \\
                   \midrule

                   Wiedererkennen Tag 2 & & &&  \\
\midrule
       &  Gesamt     & -.201  & -.295 & -.079    \\
         \midrule
        & Neutral         & -.179       &  -.252 & -.082  \\
         \midrule
        & Negativ     &  -.182     & -.280 & -.059  \\
                   \midrule
       \end{tabular}
   \end{threeparttable}

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\small
    \textit{Anmerkungen.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
    \end{minipage}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
 i wonder why you use `threeparttable` if you not like its functionality. to my taste also you have to many rules in table. with use of `siunitx` your numbers will be set in math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore}
      \label{tab:KorrelationenBilder}
\centering
      \begin{tabular}{ll*{3}{S[table-format=-1.3]}}
    \toprule
    &   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Pupillenweite} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
    &   &   {Gesamt}    &   {Neutral}   &   {Negativ}   \\
    \midrule
Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1  &   &   &   &       \\
%    \midrule
    &   Gesamt  &  .000 & -.112 &  .096     \\
    &   Neutral & -.146 & -.192 & -.070     \\
    &   Negativ &  .086 & -.042 &  .172     \\
    \midrule
Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2  &   &   &   &       \\
%    \midrule
    &   Gesamt  & -.135 & -.223 & -.036     \\
    &   Neutral & -.286 & -.293 & -.219     \\
    &   Negativ & -.013 & -.136 &  .087     \\
    \midrule
Wiedererkennen Tag 3    &   &   &   &       \\
%    \midrule
    &   Gesamt  & -.201 & -.295 & -.079     \\
    &   Neutral & -.179 & -.252 & -.082     \\
    &   Negativ & -.182 & -.280 & -.059     \\
    \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}

\smallskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\small
\textit{Anmerkungen.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
\end{minipage}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I was looking for. I have never worked with `minipage` before and it works perfectly. Could you explain why the caption is wider now in your MWE than in mine without using a `minipage` for that as well? And I can't see a difference when I use or not use the `siunitx` package. I read that it is for the presentation of numbers. Could you tell me what it changes in this example? Thanks! :)

Comment: (i) caption is now outside of `threeparttable` environment, consequently it is not limited to its width anymore. (ii) without `minipage` the text below would be centered. (iii) with use of `siunitx` signs at numbers would be present correctly (iv) i wonder why you use `threeparttable` if you not like its functionality. see addendum to my answer.